# Cyberpower Rack Mount Cable connectors

Tags: batteries, identification, connector

I have a Cyberpower rack mount UPS that has a 4 battery pack and something shorted and need to replace the cables and connectors. Been trying to search and find what kind of connector it is, but basically if you look in the connector, it just has spade male or female connectors housed in this plastic shell, just not sure what the shell part number so I can order replacements. See picture.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Calling Davide Andrea.

Comment: those cables look ok ... why do you need to replace them?

Comment: Eh, the spade connector on one of them partially melted, lol...kind of hard to get picture but will see what I can do but they are 4 batteries and 24v and something wasn't right when I plug seemed to short, bright light etc...unplugged and the one terminal heated up. Odd since the batteries are connected with fuses they did not blow so still scratching my head as to what happened. Added additional pic...

Comment: You should be able to use fully-insulated 1/4" quick disconnects with those; the overmolding is likely proprietary.

Comment: Thanks, yeah from what I can see I think its so you can only plug in black to black and red to red etc. Still not sure what the issue was but I must not have had something not hooked up correctly. I have added a picture of the wiring with them setting up, really do not like the wiring and how they have it laid out. Also think its odd with the 2 negative leads and 2 positive leads, I measure 12v from one output on the red and one output on the negative.

Comment: oops meant measure 24v red to black for each lead...